# f:validateDoubleRange not working when added currency symbol added to that textbox

Tags: java, jsf, xhtml

I am new to jsf. i am adding currency validation for textbox.I am using f:validateDoubleRange for validating textbox with some minimum and maximum characters.My textbox working fine when we haven't currency added but if i added currency to that textbox f:validateDoubleRange not working.Can anyone help me to get out this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use custom converter for currency display.

Answer (score 1):

```
<f:validateDoubleRange minimum="20.00" maximum="20000.99" />
```

Here , the **minimum** and **maximum** properties are type of javax.el.ValueExpression and must evaluate to **java.lang.Double** . So you can't validate values which include currency symbol.

If you want to validate these values, you can use `<f:validateRegex>` or custom validator.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a converter instead: f:convertNumber type="currency"
The converter has other attributes to control the formatting see java doc http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserverfaces/2.2/vdldocs/facelets/f/convertNumber.html